# class variable in service in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angular-services

Im developing a simple Account Management page where a user can login, register etc

Each section has its own controller. i.e The login page has a login controller.
These controllers share a common service `AccountService` to handle the login, register mechanics.

**This is my `AccountService`:**

```
app.service('AccountService', function($http){
    var user = {};

    this.isLoggedIn = function(){
        return user.isAuth;
    };

    this.login = function(user, callback){
      //...//  
      if(success){
          //Mark user as authenticated
          user.isAuth = true;  
      }
    };  
});
```

As you can see, if I login by doing `AccountService.login(user)` the variable `user.isAuth` is set to true upon success. **BUT** the problem is if I then call `AccountService.isLoggedIn()` I expect the function to return `true` but it returns undefined

For example if I do:

```
app.controller('LoginController', function($scope, AccountService) {
    $scope.login = function(user) {
        //Do Login
        AccountService.login(user, function(r){
            result = r;
        });                            //At this point user.isAuth should be true

        //Check if user is logged in
        console.log(AccountService.isLoggedIn()); //This returns false
    }
}
```

**So how do I persist the variables in a service?**

---

**Edit**
@itcouldevenbeaboat suggested that the value is not set before the second function is called due to the asynchronous call. However it still doesn't work when I separate the function call from each other like so:

```
app.controller('LoginController', function($scope, AccountService) {
    $scope.login = function(user) {
        //Do Login
        AccountService.login(user, function(r){
            result = r;
        });                            //At this point user.isAuth should be true
    }
    $scope.isAuth = function(){
        //Check if user is logged in
        console.log(AccountService.isLoggedIn()); //This STILL returns false
    }
}
```

I still get a false when I call the `login` function and then the `isAuth` function on the `LoginController`

Comment: var user = []; should be var user = {}; no ?

Comment: @ex0ns oops, yes my bad, that was a type but still the question doesn't change, the variable user is empty

Answer (score 2):

Your login function is asyncronous. So the `console.log` is actually running before the data comes back.

Try this instead,

```
$scope.login = function(user) {
    //Do Login
    AccountService.login(user, function(r){
        result = r;
        console.log(AccountService.isLoggedIn()); //This returns true
    });                            
}
```

Comment: Your answer seems convincing but when i tried it it didn't work. Have a look at my edit. Thanks for responding though!

Comment: Hey @Krimson, I'd suggest you put together a JS Fiddle with your bug.